# Different Chapter Name by Even/Odd Page

Tags: xetex, memoir, polyglossia, books

The Chapter name that is present at the top right corner of the even page needs to be also displayed on the top left corner of the odd page, with a change. I use  polyglossia and commonly available Sanskrit fonts. The Chapter names are Sanskrit names that can be written in Roman characters using diacritics. Is there a way, I can write the Romanized form on say the even page and the corresponding Sanskrit version on the odd page.

Currently it is represented as below:
[image]

My platform is xelatex, memoir class. To write in sanskrit, I use the RomDev mapping scheme that allows me to write Sanskrit text using Roman characters and have macros that allow me to write text and generate both versions. To solve this, the actual language is not important. Can this be done, say using regular font on even page and bold font on odd page by a single declaration of chapter name? (`\chapter{Nāda}`)

Comment: A minimal working example (MWE) would make it easier to for us to test possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to take it from here.

```
\documentclass{memoir}%
\newcommand{\altchapter}[1]% #1 = alternate chapter title
{\makeoddhead{headings}{\textsl{\normalsize CHAPTER \thechapter. \MakeUppercase{#1}}}%
 {}{\normalsize\thepage}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{I am at loss for words}
\altchapter{Sanskrit chapter title}
\newpage
this page intentionally left blank.
\newpage
this page intentionally left blank.
\end{document}
```

Comment: made some minor changes. It should be possible to re-define how chapter is defined, as far as font and numbering goes?

Comment: If you can show me how to translate the chapter title (not to mention the word "CHAPTER"), I can show you how to redefine \chapter to combine both titles.

Comment: It is actually transliteration. See http://cikitsa.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-do-i-install-romdev-mapping-for.html and http://cikitsa.blogspot.com/2010/07/xelatex-for-sanskrit.html